# playing audio in HTML5 after changing source with jQuery

Tags: jquery, audio

The strangest thing: I have a jQuery function that changes the source of an audio player. It works if I insert an "alert()" in between. But otherwise it returns NaN.

jQuery:

```
$('.playpause').click(function(){

  if (playmode==false){

    audio = $('#player audio').get(0);
    $(audio).attr('src','newurl.mp3');
    playmode = true;
    /*alert('wait a minute!');*/
    audio.play();
  } 
  else {
  audio.pause();
  playmode = false;}
})
```

I imagine it has something to do with the browser not having the time to load the data? Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest creating your audio objects directly to avoid issues like this.

Comment: but what if I want the user to be able to choose from dozens of songs? create dozens of audio objects?

Comment: What difference does that make?  Just create a new Audio instance for each thing you want to play.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly with me :>>

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.button').click(function(){
                var myAudio=$(".playpause");     
                var audioSub = myAudio.get(0); 
                var playmode=audioSub.paused;  
                if (playmode){      
                    myAudio.attr('src','song.mp3');
                    playmode = true;     
                    audioSub.play();
                } 
                else {
                    audioSub.pause();
                    playmode = false;}
            })
        });
    </script>
```

HTML Code :>>

```
 <button class="button" >Next</button>
            <audio controls  class="playpause">
                <source src="song0.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
                Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
            </audio>
```